# Как организовать вложенную сортировку?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Суть задачи отображена на картинке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Просьба знающих в SQL набросать идеи и приемы, как можно такое реализовать

Comment: ORDER BY clause может иметь составное выражение сортировки. Выполняющее именно то, что описано.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что для решения проблемы достаточно прочитать учебник по SQL. ЛЮБОЙ.

Comment: @Akina, возможность использовать составное выражение сортировки известна. Я вижу загвоздку, что в этом случае вторая часть выражения отработает на подмножестве строк, имеющих одинаковое значение в колонки из первой части выражения. В моем случае это не работает, так как товары разных цветов будут иметь разное число заказов. Я знаю, что задача может оказаться типовой, но в учебниках явного ответа пока не увидел.

Comment: *В моем случае это не работает, так как **товары разных цветов будут иметь разное число заказов.*** А где об этом в вопросе хоть полслова? Продумайте формулировку, и перепишите вопрос так, чтобы ЛЮБОЙ, кто реализует указанное (а что не указано - будет сделано как угодно!), получил один и тот же результат.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за ваш комментарий)